# angularjs directive to get all tabbable elements without using jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to implement an angularjs directive to get all tabbable elements on a view. I have found a solution using jquery-ui using the ":tabbable" selector, but I'd rather not include this library. Pure jquery is acceptable, though.

Comment: Have you looked at the jquery ui code for this? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0bfbd21d4fefa98d165b7d50277bd23be84e919a/ui/tabbable.js Might look at re-creating from taking this code. And Focusable: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/52d9ec6c4d7402d5ef04b8c7959f812f8d095cef/ui/focusable.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var children = _.sortBy($('.project :tabbable'), function(child) {
            var aChild = angular.element(child);
            return parseInt(aChild.attr('tabindex')) || 0;
        });
```

This code will return all the tabbable elements which lies into `.project` class.